# Recursive search by file list

Tags: batch-file

I have a TXT file with a list of names like:

```
Test
Word
etc.
```

I need to search ( recursive, so also in subfolder ) if one of that name match with a file. This is my attempt:

```
@echo off

Set MyPath=C:\Folder

for /f %%i in (list.txt) do (
echo File with word %%i: >> result.txt
echo. >> result.txt
findstr /M /C:%%i /S "%MyPath%\*.*" >> result.txt
echo. >> result.txt
)
```

The result.txt i want is:

```
File with word test: 

C:\Folder\test.exe
C:\Folder\my test.txt
C:\Folder\another test.doc
C:\Folder\tatest.bat

File with word Word: 

C:\Folder\This is my word.exe
C:\Folder\CoolWord.txt
C:\Folder\hello word.bat
```

So how to improve that batch and make it recursive also for the subfolder of the initial dir?

Thanks

Comment: if you do the recursive lookup for more than one word, it would make sense to do the `dir` only once and use that data for the search: `dir /s /b *.* >allfiles.txt` `for /f %%i in (list.txt) do (... findstr /m /c:%%i "allfiles.txt" ...)` so the time consuming search through the files is done only once.

Comment: Plase post an example and i'll check it out, thanks

Comment: it's just minor change to your code. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:  It will write result.txt with the results for each word.

```
@echo off
(
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("list.txt") do (
   echo "File with word %%a:"
   echo.
   set "flag="
      for /r "c:\folder" %%b in ("*%%a*") do (echo %%b&set flag=1)
   if not defined flag echo No Matches
   echo.
   )
)>"result.txt"
```

Comment: I prefer only one report for every match like my post. I need to set the folder, i can't search in the same folder of the batch. Your example is recursive. P.S. If the list.txt has a blank line it search for every file in the dir

Comment: Test the minor changes above.  It is recursive.

Comment: Ok, only a little tip. The report is "mixed" and not separated by a phrase like "File with word xyz:" like my first post and is difficult to read for me ( the list.txt contain many many word ). Can you provide a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Try the edited code above.  Any blank line in `list.txt` will be ignored, your search term is matching all those files, plus it matches in the short filename too if the term isn't specific enough.

Comment: Is still perferct thank you but i need only another little thing, there isn't an error checking if the word don't match any file. I have try with `If %%b=="" (echo no match) else (echo %%b)` but don't give the expected result

Comment: Give me "No Match" at the end of every matched group like "File with word xyz" " "filexyz1" "filexyz2" "No match" ---

Comment: Tested, now "no match" don't apper with matched file but with "no matched" words i don't see nothing ( like the first version without error checking )

Comment: Copy and paste the code again. And then search in the file for `no matches` after you make sure that there is a term that doesn't give you any matches.

Comment: About error checking i have resolved by myself using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` so in that case the variable is evaluated every time

Comment: delayed expansion won't help here. There was a misplaced double quote and it now works here in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /s /b C:\Folder\*.* >allfiles.txt 
for /f %%i in (list.txt) do (
  echo File with word %%i: >> result.txt
  echo. >> result.txt
  findstr /M /C:%%i /S "allfiles.txt" >> result.txt
  echo. >> result.txt
)
```

Comment: Thanks but i think the code provided by foxidrive is better then mine

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

Set MyPath=C:\Folder

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do (
   echo File with word %%i:
   echo/
   dir /B /S "%MyPath%\*%%i*"
   echo/
)) > result.txt
```